# ItemDataBound with repeater how to handel

Tags: c#, repeater

```
   protected void rptLastPromotion_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
                HtmlAnchor aView = (HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("aDescription");
                Label lbldescriptionlink = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblDescription");
                Label lbldescriptionNoLink = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblDescription2");
                HiddenField hfIsNewTab = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hfNewTab");

                for (int i = 0; i <= rptLastPromotion.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(aView.HRef))
                    {
                        lbldescriptionlink.Visible = true;
                        lbldescriptionNoLink.Visible = false;
                        if (Convert.ToBoolean(hfIsNewTab.Value) == true)
                        {
                            aView.Target = "_blank";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lbldescriptionlink.Visible = false;
                        lbldescriptionNoLink.Visible = true;
                    }

                }

            }
```

I want to handle and view the item in the repeater, but there is an error in my code. Any help in this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is extremely vague, but I believe your problem may be that you are not checking the repeater item ItemType. The standard means of doing this is:

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
```

Also, there is no need to loop on the repeater's item. (`for (int i = 0; i <= rptLastPromotion.Items.Count; i++)`) That is what the ItemDataBound event is for.

So your code would now look like this.

```
protected void rptLastPromotion_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
                HtmlAnchor aView = (HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("aDescription");
                Label lbldescriptionlink = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblDescription");
                Label lbldescriptionNoLink = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblDescription2");
                HiddenField hfIsNewTab = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hfNewTab");

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(aView.HRef))
                    {
                        lbldescriptionlink.Visible = true;
                        lbldescriptionNoLink.Visible = false;
                        if (Convert.ToBoolean(hfIsNewTab.Value) == true)
                        {
                            aView.Target = "_blank";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lbldescriptionlink.Visible = false;
                        lbldescriptionNoLink.Visible = true;
                    }

              }
            }
```

If I am not understanding/answering your question, you may want to expand your original question with some more details and explanation.

Comment: Did this answer help? Do you have any questions about it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `ItemType` inside `ItemDataBound` event of `Repeater`.

```
protected void rptLastPromotion_ItemDataBound(object sender,System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)  
{  
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)  
    {
          // write your logic here             
    }
}
```